# How to get distinct rows with all columns between two dates in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct-values

I'm trying to get all records with uniq serial numbers between two dates. But I couldn't write correct sql.

Here is my current sql query and results. There are 3 records with two XYZABC1230 serial number.

```
select * from t_recorded_test
where  office_id = '1710011001123'
and    record_date > '2017-11-01'
and    record_date < '2017-12-08'
and    test_result = 'true';

MODEM_MODEL MODEM_SERIAL_NUMBER OFFICE_ID       RECORD_DATE             RECORD_ID                           TEST_RESULT
Type2ModelB XYZABC1230          1710011001123   2017-11-01 19:35:54.0   ccf57f20d585424abc9bce781ada9dcc    TRUE
Type2ModelB XYZABC1230          1710011001123   2017-11-01 19:33:54.0   168ce13ed9644f128f7769432ad6ba2f    TRUE
Type2ModelB XYZABC12312         1710011001123   2017-12-03 19:33:54.0   ab727f836c354f159703565b9eed3331    TRUE
```

but I expect just two records XYZABC1230 and XYZABC12312. How can I do it?

EDIT:

I need just one result for all the same serial numbers. Date not important, but I have to use it for limit.

Comment: which RECORD_ID you need? if you specify that one you will have only one.

Comment: Do you only want the `modem_serial_number` in your result set? If you need more columns, what rule do you want used to select that record?

Comment: What do you mean by WITH ALL COLUMNS, when you may only want one row out of two or three with the same serial number? Maybe you didn't actually mean "all columns"? Otherwise please explain, as it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Surely those date expressions should be like `date '2017-11-01'` (a date literal), not `'2017-11-01'` (a string).

Comment: yes @mathguy is right! I thought, I want just one result with same serials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--This is for MSSQL Server
    with CTE as(
    select *,(row_number() over (partition by MODEM_SERIAL_NUMBER order by MODEM_SERIAL_NUMBER)) 'ROW_N'  from T_RECORDED_TEST   
    where OFFICE_ID='1710011001123' and RECORD_DATE > '2017-11-01' and RECORD_DATE < '2017-12-08' and TEST_RESULT = 'TRUE')
    select MODEM_MODEL,MODEM_SERIAL_NUMBER,OFFICE_ID,RECORD_DATE,RECORD_ID,TEST_RESULT  from CTE where ROW_N=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) function and `MAX(ROWID)` assuming you want the latest row on the group by values.

```
SELECT * FROM T_RECORDED_TEST 
WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ROWID)
    FROM T_RECORDED_TEST
    where office_id='1710011001123' 
    and record_date > '2017-11-01' 
    and record_date < '2017-12-08' 
    and test_result = 'true' 
    GROUP BY MODEM_SERIAL_NUMBER;
)
```

Comment: this won't work. you can't select multiple columns and group by one.

Comment: It can be with HQL in hibernate. Do you any idea?

Comment: Edited the answer, if you want all columns.

Answer (score 0):

The * is the culprit. If you're only interested in MODEM_SERIAL_NUMBER,  you could use distinct as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ( modem_serial_number )
FROM
    t_recorded_test
WHERE
    office_id = '1710011001123'
    AND   record_date > '2017-11-01'
    AND   record_date < '2017-12-08'
    AND   test_result = 'true';
```

Comment: no I'm just want one result for all the same serials.